# Interface definition with C++ (deriving without losing all the overloaded operators from base)

Tags: c++, interface, eigen, eigen3

I want to replace a part of a library with the Eigen library.
Because there are a lot of dependencies, I wanted to write an Eigen based interface.

This interface below uses cxx11 typedefs and overloading to recreate the old class interface for a 3D vector. The problem with this approach is that it seems that I have to reimplement all the operator functions/constructors which already exist in Eigen (+/-/*/..).

The example below illustrates the problem. If I use the overloaded operators of Eigen with my derived class, I get a compiler error. The base class works fine as expected. Is there a way to add the desired interface functions/members to the Eigen classes with less effort? E.g. by automatically converting the derived classes to base classes? I totally don't want to reimplement all Eigen functions :D

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Core>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>


namespace InterfDef {
    template <class T>
    using Vector3 = Eigen::Matrix<T, 3, 1>;
};

namespace InterfImp {
    template <class T>
    class Vector3 : public InterfDef::Vector3<T> {
    public:
        // This is all what I wanted to add :)
        T &x = (*this)[0];
        T &y = (*this)[1];
        T &z = (*this)[2];

        // All this crap below, I don't want to implement :(
        Vector3(InterfDef::Vector3<T> v) :
            InterfDef::Vector3<T>(v) {

        }

        Vector3(T x, T y, T z) :
            InterfDef::Vector3<T>(x,y,z) {

        }

        Vector3& operator=(const InterfDef::Vector3<T>& v) {
            (*this)[0] = v[0];
            (*this)[1] = v[2];
            (*this)[2] = v[2];
            return *this;
        }
    };
};
```

Here comes to problem. Calling the scalar multiplication operator only works for the non-derived class, because the conversion of the vector class fails after deriving.

```
int main() {
    InterfDef::Vector3<float> a(1,2,3);
    InterfImp::Vector3<float> b(2,3,4);
    InterfImp::Vector3<float> c(a);
    InterfImp::Vector3<float> d = b;

    cout << "Hello World!" << c.x << "; " << c.y << "; " << c.z << std::endl;
    cout << "Hello World!" << d.x << "; " << d.y << "; " << d.z << std::endl;

    InterfImp::Vector3<float> e = 2 * d; // error with my derived class 
    InterfDef::Vector3<float> e = 2 * d; // works

    cout << "Hello World!" << e[0] << "; " << e[1] << "; " << e[2] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## First thing

You shell use Matrix x(), y(), z() functions. If the matrix isn't const, they return a **reference** to its scalar, which make your code looks like that:

```
Vector3d a;
a.x() = 1;// Ok, a.x() is l-value
a.y() = 2;// ""
a.y() = 3;// ""
```

Notice that this isn't valid, since the matrix is constant:

```
const Vector3d b;
b.x() = 1;// Error! b.x() is r-value
```

## And for other needs...

Eigen has document **exactly** what you want to do, and even the way you try to do it, in [Customizing/Extending Eigen page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizingEigen.html).

I'll be just repeating what that is said there:

### First solution - conversion constructor

You can always use conversion constructor taking template:

```
InterfImp {
    template <class T>
    class Vector3 : public InterfDef::Vector3<T> {
        //...
        // This constructor allows you to construct Vector3 from Eigen expressions
        template<typename OtherDerived>
        Vector3(const Eigen::MatrixBase<OtherDerived>& other)
            : InterfDef::Vector3::Vector3d(other)
        { }

        // This method allows you to assign Eigen expressions to Vector3
        template<typename OtherDerived>
        Vector3& operator= (const Eigen::MatrixBase <OtherDerived>& other)
        {
            this->Base::operator=(other);
            return *this;
        }
    };
}
```

This way, even know some functions return Matrix expression(MatrixBase), you would convert them.

Notice how you had should implement the operator=.

### Second solution - Eigen plugin macros

Eigen allows you to customize it's classes, since it's a header only library.
Define EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN to the header you want to inject to MarixBase class, before you include Eigen:

```
#define EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN my_matrixbase_injection.h
// Now safely include Eigen headers
```

And in my_matrixbase_injection.h:

```
    // Add what you want to add here.
    void superCoolFunc() const
    {
        std::cout << "Super COOL!!!\n";
    }
```